# Get a typed value from an Avro GenericRecord

Tags: java, avro

Given a [GenericRecord](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericRecord.html), what is the recommended way to retrieve a typed value, as opposed to an Object? Are we expected to cast the values, and if so what is the mapping from [Avro types](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/api/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.Type.html) to Java types? For example, Avro *Array* == Java *Collection*; and Avro *String* == Java [*Utf8*](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/api/java/org/apache/avro/util/Utf8.html).

Since every GenericRecord contains its schema, I was hoping for a type-safe way to retrieve values.

Comment: Have you tried reading one non-trivial object in a `GenericRecord` ? Sometimes, direct experiment provides faster answer ;-)

Comment: Yes, I learned the Array and String mappings through trial-and-error. I would prefer to avoid casting altogether; but if that is the only way, I would prefer casting to an official (or at least verified) set of mappings as opposed to whatever implementations happen to be used in one specific version of Avro.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Avro has eight primitive types and five complex types (excluding *unions* which are a combination of other types). The following table maps these 13 Avro types to their input interfaces (the Java types which can be `put` into a `GenericRecord`) and their output implementations (the concrete Java types which are returned by a `get` from a `GenericRecord`). The values apply to Avro 1.7.7.

`╔═══════════╦════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ Avro Type ║    Input Interface     ║   Output Implementation   ║
╠═══════════╬════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║ null      ║                        ║ null                      ║
║ boolean   ║ java.lang.Boolean      ║ java.lang.Boolean         ║
║ int       ║ java.lang.Integer      ║ java.lang.Integer         ║
║ long      ║ java.lang.Long         ║ java.lang.Long            ║
║ float     ║ java.lang.Float        ║ java.lang.Float           ║
║ double    ║ java.lang.Double       ║ java.lang.Double          ║
║ bytes     ║ java.nio.ByteBuffer    ║ java.nio.HeapByteBuffer   ║
║ string    ║ java.lang.CharSequence ║ org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 ║
║ record    ║ *.GenericRecord        ║ *.GenericData$Record      ║
║ enum      ║ java.lang.CharSequence ║ *.GenericData$EnumSymbol  ║
║ array     ║ java.util.Collection   ║ *.GenericData$Array       ║
║ map       ║ java.util.Map          ║ java.util.HashMap         ║
║ fixed     ║ *.GenericFixed         ║ *.GenericData$Fixed       ║
╚═══════════╩════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════╝`

`* == org.apache.avro.generic`

---

In Avro 1.8.0, the `enum` type [requires](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-997) a `GenericEnumSymbol`. It no longer accepts `CharSequence`.

Comment: Do you remember where the table is from?

Answer (score 3):

GenericRecords in Avro won't give you a type safe way since it is all figured out at runtime. You can add wrappers that help, but at the end of the day your code needs to implicitly know what it is working with.

If you want a type safe way, you need to use serialize into a Java SpecificRecord class which can be generated with the Avro maven plugin.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any insight into the types for casting?