# How to write map to avro in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, avro

how do I write a java.util.map to avro ?
In GenericData I see entries for Record etc, but not for Map.
Same question is there on http://apache-avro.679487.n3.nabble.com/How-to-write-an-AVRO-map-Something-like-GenericData-Map-td3407527.html , but I dont understand exactly how it was done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avro uses `java.util.HashMap` directly. You do not need to convert it to another type. Specifically, there is no `GenericData` class representing a map, so you simply put your `HashMap` directly into a `GenericRecord`.

All of the Avro to Java conversions are listed in the table in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34234039/1371329). Note that `GenericData` classes are required for `record`, `enum`, `array`, and `fixed` types, but not for `map`.

Answer (score 2):

A map can be defined in avro like below. Note, the following will not work

```
{ "name": "id", "type": "map", "values" : "long" }
```

it has to be defined like this

```
{ "name": "id", "type": { "type": "map", "values" : "long" } }
```

e.g.

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "MyData",
    "fields": [
        { "name": "id", "type": { "type": "map", "values" : "long" } }
    ]
}
```